# XCopy works for a user but not for a service

Tags: service

I have TFS running an automated build.  The solution runs a cmd file which runs out batch file and then performs and xcopy at the end to copy the results to our release PC.

If I run the cmd file manually the files copy over.
If I run it in the automated build then it fails with an Access denied cannot create directory error (the directory is there).

Is there an issue with sevices creating directories on other PCs or anything like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted - the PC name needed to be added as a user on the remote machine in order to have access rights!